# Как добавить частично прозрачное изображение на Tkinter Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

Есть картинка с загруглениями на углах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Серый цвет - это пустота. Так вот, рисую я эту картинку:

```
card1_img = PhotoImage(file=("src/1h.gif"))  
lab1 = Label(image=card1_img, bd=0)
lab1.image = card1_img
lab1.place(relx=0.5, rely=1, anchor=E)
```

В итоге получается это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Неважно, что другая картинка - это другой пример. Суть в том, что вокруг моей картинки образуется рамка прямоугольника.

Можно ли ее убрать, оставив лишь изображение, то есть сделать рамку белого цвета прозрачной?

Comment: прозрачность и так должна поддерживаться, [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26088803/4279).

Comment: вроде бы формат gif [не поддерживает альфа-канал (прозрачность), в отличие от, например, png](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/png-gif). может быть, это всё-таки важно, что картинка — **другая**?

Comment: Не, если рисовать эту картинку с помощью Canvas, таких белых рамок нет и прозрачность поддерживается, но если рисовать Canvas'ом то все не работает

Answer (score 1):

GIF, действительно, поддерживает alpha-канал. Tkinter умеет с ним работать. Но виджеты Tkinter не поддерживают прозрачность (см. комментарии к [вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359934/is-there-a-way-to-make-just-the-label-background-invisible-transparent-using-tki)), поэтому белая полоса вокруг Вашей картинки - это границы виджета Label.
Везде рекомендуют для таких целей использовать Canvas.